# Problems about appending new state to old state in redux thunk

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

[IMAGE LINK HERE. it doubles the initial return.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GW3cf.png)

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import axios from 'axios'

let url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/posts'

const initialState = {
    allPosts: [],
    isLoading: false,
    isError: false,
}

export const getAllPost = createAsyncThunk('allPosts/getAllPost', async (page, thunkAPI) => {
    console.log(page)
    try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(`${url}?page=${page}`)

        return data.posts
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
})

const allPostSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'allPosts',
    initialState,
    reducers: {},
    extraReducers: {
        [getAllPost.pending]: (state) => {
            state.isLoading = true
        },
        [getAllPost.fulfilled]: (state, { payload }) => {
            console.log(payload)
            state.allPosts = [...state.allPosts, ...payload]
            state.isLoading = false
        },
        [getAllPost.rejected]: (state) => {
            state.isLoading = false
            state.isError = true
        },
    },
})

export default allPostSlice.reducer
```

When I try to append `...state.allPosts`, which is supposed to be the old state, it prints double the initial payload. I only need it printed once, not twice.

```
[getAllPost.fulfilled]: (state, { payload }) => {
            console.log(payload)
            state.allPosts = [...state.allPosts, ...payload]
            state.isLoading = false
        },
```

How can I print my payload only once using `state.allPosts`?

Comment: so basically `state.allPosts` is not returning the concatenation of the state post and the received posts from the thunk?

Comment: it recieves.

but it returns... twice the payload.. it doubles on the initial request. 

it's like.. 

for example :  I REQUESTED  1 pizza for the initial state.  but it will give me back 2 the same pizza.

Comment: Try ‘state.allPosts.concat(payload)’.  Though it’s not obvious to me why your current isn’t working.  Is it possible that the thunk is getting dispatched twice?  It could be safer to do ‘state.allPosts = payload’, but only if there is no pagination.

Comment: Please specify the react version. If you are using react >18 and dispatching your thunk in useEffect, it will send two requests (If React.StrictMode is enabled). 
https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/synchronizing-with-effects#how-to-handle-the-effect-firing-twice-in-development